# How do I solve the part (a), of the following question?

Tags: computer-architecture

[image]

The problem I'm facing is how do I know whether the mapping is "1-way set associative", "2-way set associative", "4- way set associative", etc.

Please help!

Comment: Homework questions are off topic here. You should first learn basics and try by your own. It's pretty easy to see set size. Cache block size is 8 words & the size of set is 256 words which is 256/8 = 32. Therefore there are 32 blocks per set.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma.Do you mean to say that it is 32 way set associative mapping?

Comment: Yeah, $k$ blocks per set is $k-way$ set associating mapping.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).  Also, make sure to give attribution to the source of that material!

Answer (score 0):

It's 32 way set associative mapping. How?

Each cache line has one block and it is given that one block has 8 words. 
It is already given it is a set associative mapping with set size as 256 words or 256/8 = 32 blocks (or 32 cache lines. As, each cache line holds one block). Hence it is 32 way set-associative mapping.